# Decryption of a RSA encrypted message is not working.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, cryptography

Using RSA with e=13 (encrypting power), d=17 (decrypting power) & n=33 (RSA modulus)  I noticed that once I decrypted the encrypted message it would be different then the original message. Why is that??

I used the primes p=11 & q=3 to get the modulus n=33.
So the totient Phi(n) = k = 10*2 = 20

By choosing e=13, (d*e)mod(k)=1 d is 17.

.

If I encrypt "4"

(4^13)mod(33) = 31

Decrypting "31" to get back "4"

(31^17)mod(33) = 28 (It's not working)

.

Though by using e=3 & d=7 it works. Is there a relationship to these numbers??

Comment: It would help if you would say what you mean by $e,d,n,p,q$. Not all sources use the same letters for the same things. In particular, if $n=pq$, then $q=13$ should be $q=3$.

Comment: $31^{17}=(-2)^7=-128=-7=4\pmod{11}$, but $28=6\pmod{11}$, so maybe you should check your calculation.

Comment: You're right. q=13 should be q=3. Just fixed it.

Comment: Good. Now, did you check your calculation of $31^{17}\pmod{33}$?

Comment: Yes. And now it somehow works. Thank you.

Comment: Good. Write it up, please, and post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Might as well state that it was just a precision error.

Changing (31) to (-2) "fixes" the problem, since (31)mod(33) == (-2)mod(33).

And ((-2)^17)mod(33) = (-29), where (-29)mod(33) == (4)mod(33).

So it comes down to that one should use more than 8 bytes or use smaller numbers.

Comment: Or one should calculate $a^b\pmod c$ by some method more clever than first computing $a^b$ and then reducing modulo $c$. It can be done without ever having to deal with any numbers bigger than $c^2$.